# SQLAlchemy returns weird data

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to export a date from a table. I want to just pull the raw created object out.

I am running the query below:

```
return model.Session.query(cls).filter(cls.issue_id == issue_id).order_by(desc("created")).first()
```

But it returns the entire record as so and I have no idea how to export created out.

```
<IssueComment id=32 comment=ay user_id=578042a3-d879-4b32-96a9-10f9aabe152c issue_id=19 created=2018-07-17 20:17:09.653809 visibility=visible abuse_status=0>
```

If i try calling created in cls.created as so

```
return model.Session.query(cls.created).filter(cls.issue_id == issue_id).order_by(desc("created")).first()
```

and it exports a weird datetime version. I just want the raw version

```
(datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 20, 17, 9, 653809),)
```

How can i export the value for created out as the raw string?

Comment: There is nothing _weird_ about what your query returns, it's just a normal `datetime` object, and that is part of the Python standard library.

Comment: Does `(datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 20, 17, 9, 653809),)` look right to you?

Comment: Yes. You're missing the fact that you also get tuples back from queries, regardless of the data type it contains. You need to take the 0th index and you have a perfectly normal datetime object.

Comment: In addition to the great answers you're already given,  if you want a single `datetime`, you can use `Query.scalar()` instead of `Query.first()` in the latter single attribute query. It fetches the first column of the first row for you, compared to fetching the first row, which you seem to have been confused about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SqlAlchemy queries for attributes (as opposed to the entire model) return [`KeyedTuples`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.util.KeyedTuple) (or [Row](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html?highlight=row#sqlalchemy.engine.Row) objects in SQLAlchemy 1.4) which behave like a [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). Like normal Python tuples, a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) with a single element is constructed by a trailing comma.  This is why your result `(datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 20, 17, 9, 653809),)` shows the datetime object followed by a comma.

```
>>> row = session.query(User.creation_timestamp).first()
>>> row
(datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 22, 9, 20, 56),)  # <- trailing comma because it's a tuple
```

Values can be accessed by index

```
>>> row[0]
datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 22, 9, 20, 56)
```

Or by name

```
>>> row.creation_timestamp
datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 22, 9, 20, 56)
```

The values are python objects with all their usual methods

```
>>> row.creation_timestamp.isoformat()
'2018-04-22T09:20:56'
>>> str(row.creation_timestamp)
'2018-04-22 09:20:56'
```

It is a little confusing that the [tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#returning-lists-and-scalars) says that `.first()`

> applies a limit of one and returns the first result as a scalar

and the example shows a single object being returned, like this:

```
>>> q = session.query(User).first()
>>> q
<User object at 0x7f97d8c6b590>
```

whereas calling first on your query by attribute returns a value wrapped in a tuple.  It makes sense if you consider the tuple to be a row in the resultset.  If you called `.all()` on your query you would get a list of tuples (rows).  If you called `.limit(1).all()` on your query you would get a list containing a single tuple.  So when you call `.first()` you are getting the first result from `.limit(1).all()`, which is a tuple.

```
>>> row = session.query(User.creation_timestamp).all()
>>> row
[(datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 22, 9, 20, 56),), (datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 22, 9, 20, 56),), ...]

>>> row = session.query(User.creation_timestamp).limit(1).all()
>>> row
[(datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 22, 9, 20, 56),)]

>>> row = session.query(User.creation_timestamp).first()
>>> row
(datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 22, 9, 20, 56),)
```

Answer (score 4):

If the column is a datetime column, the raw value isn't a string, it's… well, a datetime.

In most database engines, under the covers, the *actual* raw value stored in the database for datetime columns is some kind of number. For example, IIRC, in Microsoft SQL Server, it's a 64-bit integer of decimicroseconds since 1901. But you don't want that number. What would you do with it?

If you want a string in some particular format, you can of course ask the database to format it for you to whatever string formats it accepts, but why?

Your engine and/or SQLAlchemy has represented the datetime value as a Python [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) object. That's smaller, faster to pass over the wire from the database, and more flexible (e.g., you can do comparisons and arithmetic with them) than a string.

And you can always format it to whatever string format you want. For example:

```
>>> d = datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 20, 17, 9, 653809)
>>> str(d)
'2018-07-17 20:17:09.653809'
>>> d.isoformat()
'2018-07-17T20:17:09.653809'
>>> d.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
'20180717201709'
>>> d.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p%S')
'07/17/18 08:18 PM'
```

… and so on.

Comment: The problem is even if i do str(d) it still returns `(datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 17, 20, 17, 9, 653809),)` which isnt even formatted correctly.